# Making Html Table Column Headers Sortable With Exception

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I am trying to add a sort to each of my column headers in my html table. There are lots of addins you can add to do this but I have a different scenario which makes it a little bit harder.

This is what my table looks like:

[image]

Every object has 3 table rows. The first row is the row that I want to sort by and ignore the last two rows. But when sorting I want to move all three rows together. In the image above the first object (3 table rows - red) has the last two rows showing but the second object (4th table row - green) has the last two rows hidden. What is the best way to get this table sortable without messing up the rows?

It seems like i need to sort by 3 rows at a time and only sort based on the td content in the first of the 3 rows.

Comment: http://phrogz.net/JS/sorTable/sorTable_docs.html has this feature (as I'm sure many other libraries do). See the `sort-withprevious` or `sort-tbodies` options.

Comment: @Phrogz This actually looks pretty good. From what I saw i should be able to just add the sort-with-previous on the last two rows of each object.

Comment: Do you happen to know of any table filters that do this as well?

Comment: Correct. Or, wrap all related rows in their own `<tbody>` and use `sort-tbodies`. No, I do not follow or keep track of other libraries that also do this. However, I strongly suspect (untested) that my sorTable code will work with my [Filterlicious](http://phrogz.net/JS/Filterlicious/) code. Though...wow, that is some super-old code. :)